# unfortunely "application" has stopped in emulator .What is the solution?

Tags: java, android

**this is what logcat said :**
what is the problem?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:234)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:53)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3650)
                      at com.example.una.basketcounter2.MainActivity.displaypoinB(MainActivity.java:50)
                      at com.example.una.basketcounter2.MainActivity.klik3poinB(MainActivity.java:58)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Application terminated.
```

**This is my java code**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
        int poinA = 0;
        int poinB = 0;

    public void displaypoinA (int poin){
        TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poinTimA);
        label.setText(poin);

    }


    public void klik3poinA (View view){

        poinA= poinA + 3;
        displaypoinA (poinA);

    }

    public void klik2poinA (View view){

        poinA= poinA + 2;
        displaypoinA (poinA);

    }

    public void klik1poinA (View view){

        poinA= poinA + 1;
        displaypoinA (poinA);
    }



    public void displaypoinB (int poin){
        TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poinTimB);
        label.setText(poin);

    }


    public void klik3poinB (View view){

        poinB= poinB + 3;
        displaypoinB (poinB);

    }

    public void klik2poinB (View view){

        poinB= poinB + 2;
        displaypoinB (poinB);

    }

    public void klik1poinB (View view){

        poinB= poinB + 1;
        displaypoinB (poinB);


    }
}
```

Comment: Search on google `Could not execute method for android:onClick`

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line in all place when you are doing setText()

```
     label.setText(String.valueOf(poin));
```

**Because you are passing int value in setText().**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
label.setText(""+poin);
```

Hope this will work. let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Remember textview accepts only string value if you want show int, float, double etc you need to add " " with the value in textview like below.

```
label.setText("" + poin);
```

OR

```
label.setText(String.valueOf(poin));
```

Use Below Code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    int poinA = 0;
    int poinB = 0;

    public void displaypoinA(int poin) {
        TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poinTimA);
        label.setText("" + poin);

    }


    public void klik3poinA(View view) {

        poinA = poinA + 3;
        displaypoinA(poinA);

    }

    public void klik2poinA(View view) {

        poinA = poinA + 2;
        displaypoinA(poinA);

    }

    public void klik1poinA(View view) {

        poinA = poinA + 1;
        displaypoinA(poinA);
    }


    public void displaypoinB(int poin) {
        TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poinTimB);
        label.setText("" + poin);

    }


    public void klik3poinB(View view) {

        poinB = poinB + 3;
        displaypoinB(poinB);

    }

    public void klik2poinB(View view) {

        poinB = poinB + 2;
        displaypoinB(poinB);

    }

    public void klik1poinB(View view) {

        poinB = poinB + 1;
        displaypoinB(poinB);


    }
}
```